# Rendering Symbol font to PDF with Aspose Slides

Tags: aspose-slides

I am using Aspose Slides to convert user generated PPTX files to PDF. We have a file where the user has used the Symbol font, which when rendered into a PDF displays only as a box.

I have tried embedding the font, but that does not seem to work.

Here is the relevant code

```
PdfOptions pdfOptions = new PdfOptions()
{
    EmbedFullFonts = true
};
ppt.Save(outputStream, SaveFormat.Pdf, pdfOptions);
pdfBytes = outputStream.ToArray();
```

The result is empty squares in place of the symbols.

[Example of failed rendering](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KZAPW.png)

[Example of symbols that are not being rendered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NFwde.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@SeeBee,

I have observed the images shared by you and like to share that you need to make sure that the fonts used in presentation must be available in Machine where you are trying to export to PDF. If there is still an issue then please provide the source presentation that you have sued on your end so that we may investigate the issue further on our end. I also suggest you to please try using latest Aspose.Slides for .NET 18.3 on your end as well.

I am working as Support developer/ Evangelist at Aspose.